# issue in accessing ORC transactional table through apache drill

Tags: hive, apache-drill

Issue while accessing ORC transactional hive table through apache drill.

- Apache drill 1.10.0
- Hive 1.2.1

Below is the error coming while accessing data from the mentioned table through apache drill.

> Query Failed: An Error Occurred
>
> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000112_0000" [Error Id: ad9b4243-d48d-43c7-9755-388202d7c54d on inbbrdssvm16.india.tcs.com:31010]

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: It seems to me that data in a column has a row with the string `0000112_0000` but the type of that column is number. Hence the NumberFormatException.

Comment: seems to be an issue with ORC transactional tables,which is not supported by apache drill 1.10.

Comment: The support is cming in apache drill 1.13,but for that we need to upgrade hive version to 2.1.0.But we want to know some kind of work around around hive 1.2.1 version.

Comment: Querying transactional table should work with Drill 1.10/Hive 1.2.1 combination. I have seen this issue when Hive 2.1 transactional tables are accessed using Drill 1.10.

Comment: For me it is  not working,could you please share your storage plugin for hive connection

Comment: I have hive storage plugin def as in document - https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/#connect-drill-to-the-hive-remote-metastore .  

I believe it may not be related to storage plugin def. Can you share the output of hadoop fs -ls -R  <hive table external location>? And which hadoop distribution are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move onto latest Drill and Hive versions.
This issue is resolved in Apache Drill 1.13.0 version
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5978